# Incompatible types found

Tags: java

I am working on a project and I am getting stuck on what I think is the final part. I have one class: Volt, which involves the following segment of code:

```
 public Volt scaleByFactor(double scalar) {

    public Point getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    double tempX = (end.getX() - start.getX()) * scalar + start.getX();
    double tempY = (end.getY() - start.getY()) * scalar + start.getY();


    //There is another class: public Point(double x, double y)
    Point s = new Point(tempX, tempY);
    Volt sls = new Volt(start, s);
    return sls;
```

And another class: Sweep, with the following segment of code:

```
    Point p1 = new Point(X1, Y1);
    Point p2 = new Point(X2, Y2);
    Volt ls = new Volt(p1, p2);
    Point newPoint = ls.scaleByFactor(scalar);
```

What is happening is: when I compile I get told: 
incompatible types
found   : Volt
required: Point

Now I understand that means I need to use the type point instead of the type Volt but I do not know just how it is done?

Comment: you have methods within methods...

Comment: @Reimeus You need to make it answer...

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that you have methods inside methods (which is not allowed in Java). Problem occurs here:

```
Point newPoint = ls.scaleByFactor(scalar);
```

You declare a variable of type `Point` but you assign the result of `scaleByFactor` to it. `scaleByFactor` returns a `Volt` object so you can't assign it to a `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about the intended functionality, but try this:

```
 public Point scaleByFactor(double scalar) {
    double tempX = (end.getX() - start.getX()) * scalar + start.getX();
    double tempY = (end.getY() - start.getY()) * scalar + start.getY();

    //There is another class: public Point(double x, double y)
    Point s = new Point(tempX, tempY);
    return s;
}
```

Or to change the other function to:

```
Point p1 = new Point(X1, Y1);
Point p2 = new Point(X2, Y2);
Volt ls = new Volt(p1, p2);
Volt newVolt = ls.scaleByFactor(scalar);
```